# Set ComboBox text on selection

Tags: delphi, combobox, delphi-7

I am working on an application where i have a combobox with long text values.Since the text values are large(in term of characters ..20 or more), to display in the combobox, the requirement was to display on the `first` character after selecting from the drop down.
Like in the image marked in red. if the user selects 3th item `3 0.5 to 1.25 Slight` i should only display the `3` in the combobox.

[image]

So i tried this

```
   sTheSelectedValue : string;

  procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Select(Sender: TObject);
  begin
   sTheSelectedValue:=TrimTextAndDisplay(ComboBox1.Text); //send theselected value
   ComboBox1.Text :='';                                   //clear the selection
   ComboBox1.Text:=sTheSelectedValue;                     //now assign as text to combo box   
   Button1.Caption:=ComboBox1.Text;                      //just show the new value on the button.
  end;


   function TForm1.TrimTextAndDisplay(TheText : string): string;
   var
   sTheResult : string;
     begin
        sTheResult :=copy(TheText,0,1); //extract the first value..
        Result     :=sTheResult;
     end;
```

The result is [image]

The button seem to show the proper value but not the combobox.

what i want is to get `3` in the combobox, i cant seem set `ComboBox1.Text:=` 
can any one tell me how to do it? 
like this on selection of from the combobox the result should be
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would suggest owner-drawing the ComboBox to handle this.  Set the `TComboBox.Style` property to `csOwnerDrawFixed`, then store just the numbers `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, etc in the `TComboBox.Items` property itself and use the `TComboBox.OnDrawItem` event to render the full strings when the drop-down list is visible, eg:

```
var
  sTheSelectedValue : string; 

const
  ItemStrings: array[0..7] of string = (
    '0 to 0.1 Calm (rippled)',
    '0.1 to 0.5 Smooth (wavelets)',
    '0.5 to 1.25 Slight',
    '1.25 to 2.5 Moderate',
    '2.5 to 4 Rough',
    '4 to 6 Very rough',
    '6 to 9 High',
    '9 to 14 Very high');

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  ComboBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for I := Low(ItemStrings) to High(ItemStrings) do begin
      ComboBox1.Items.Add(IntToStr(I+1));
    end;
  finally
    ComboBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end; 

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Select(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  sTheSelectedValue := IntToStr(ComboBox1.ItemIndex+1);
  Button1.Caption := sTheSelectedValue;
end; 

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  s: String;
begin
  if odSelected in State then begin
    ComboBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clHighlight;
    ComboBox1.Canvas.Font.Color := clHighlightText;
  end else begin
    ComboBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := ComboBox1.Color;
    ComboBox1.Canvas.Font.Color := ComboBox1.Font.Color;
  end;
  ComboBox1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  s := IntToStr(Index+1);
  if not (odComboBoxEdit in State) then begin
    s := s + ' ' + ItemStrings[Index];
  end;
  ComboBox1.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left+2, Rect.Top+2, s);
  if (State * [odFocused, odNoFocusRect]) = [odFocused] then begin
    ComboBox1.Canvas.DrawFocusRect(Rect);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to try to save the data in a record, for ex:

```
 type
 TMyRec = record
  Num:Integer;
  Text:String;
end;

TMyRecArray = array of TMyRec;

MyRecArray:TMyRecArray;
```

then you can set manually the items to be set in the ComboBox (**on the OnFromCreate**),

```
SetLength(MyRecArray,9);
MyRecArray[0].Num:=1;
MyRecArray[0].Text:='0 to 0.1 Calm Rippled';
.
.
```

and so on.

then in the combobox strigns place only the numbers, and

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Select(Sender: TObject);   
var
  i:integer;     
begin         
  for i:=0 to 9 do
  begin
    if ComboBox1.Text=IntToStr(MyRecArray[i].Num) then
      Button1.Caption:=MyRecArray[i].Text; 
  end;
end;
```

Comment: ok, but this will set the `combo box` text as `TrimTextAndDisplay result` on select of the item?

Comment: no it won't, coz we will not be using the TrimTextAndDisplay, we will only set the caption of the button, is this your target? or am I missing something here? Why don't give it a try?

Comment: na, not setting the caption of the button, that button is only for test. in `ComboBox1Select` i am doing this  `ComboBox1.Text:=sTheSelectedValue;Button1.Caption:=ComboBox1.Text;` .i am assigning the newest value to combox box n then combobox value to the button..the button is showing the value i want but the combox is still showing the large text value as `3 0.5 to 1.25 Slight` where it should be showing `3` like the button is displaying

Comment: Why Don't you place a TEdit above the ComboBox, it will seem as the Combobox, but in this case you can manage the Text in the edit. Would you like to see a sample how will it look like?

Comment: u just gave a simple (awesome) idea, i will try n get back